# Find the applied ScaleTransform on a Control or UIElement?

Tags: wpf, uielement, scaletransform, layouttransform

I have a control sitting somewhere in my Window. At the root of this Window is a grid named MainGrid. I have a `ScaleTransform` applied on MainGrid's LayoutTransform that I use to zoom in on all the contents of my Window when the window's size grows. However, one of my controls uses`BitmapCache` on their canvases to optimize drawing performance. BitmapCache does not take into consideration any `ScaleTransform`s that might be applied to the control, so if I'm zoomed in, the control appears blurry.

BitmapCache does have a RenderAtScale property I can use to increase the scale of the cached image. However, the problem I have is that I don't know of an elegant way to find out what that Scale value needs to be. For now, I have a property on my control so that my Window can pass its scale value to the control. However, I would like it if I didn't need to rely on some external source passing in a scale value.

Is there any way a Control can get a summary of all the ScaleTransforms applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always recursively go through all of the Control's parents and sum their `ScaleTransform`.

I don't think you can do it any other way.

Comment: Is there a concise/elegant way to get change notification for all of the ScaleTransform changes in my control's VisualTree? If so, I may just add a helper method to all of my controls that does exactly what you suggested - recursively runs through the visual tree to get the sum of ScaleTransforms I need to apply.

Comment: you can recursively register for the changes in the ScaleTransorms of the parents also. same helper class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `PresentationSource`'s `RootVisual` to calculate the total transform of an element.  The general pattern to find the scale applied between a parent and a child is

```
Visual child = /* some visual */ this;
Visual parent = PresentationSource.FromVisual(child).RootVisual;

// calculate the transform needed to go from the parent to the child coordinate spaces
var childTransform = parent.TransformToDescendant(child);

// use the transform to scale a 1x1 rectangle
// use Inverse as the transform is from Parent coordinates to child, we want 
// child to parent
var unitRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
var transformedUnit = childTransform.Inverse.TransformBounds(unitRect);

// transformedUnit.Width and transformedUnit.Height are now the scale factors (X and Y)
Debug.Assert(transformedUnit.Width == 0.25 && transformedUnit.Height == 0.25);
```

Comment: This will however ignore any scale transforms on the way. For instance: I have a window with a slider to control scale. It is not useful to apply that scale transform rhght away to the whole "Window" (which is the RootVisual). Instead a "MainWindowControl" is taking this place and gets the ScaleTransform. Therefore it is important to sum up. (Multiply matrixes)

Comment: @Robetto, I don't understand.  The `TransformToDescendant` call will take into account all of the `.Transform`s applied in the visual tree between the nodes you specify - regardless of the transform type.  "This while loop will walk up the visual tree until we encounter the ancestor. As it does so, it will accumulate the descendent->ancestor transform." (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/src/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Visual.cs#46e3a62ee137ecab#references)

Comment: I don't see any recursion or loops in the code above. But the track is the right one. Go up by multiplying inverse on a unit square or go from the root by multiplying the transforms (but all). That was my point

Answer (score 2):

As *Elad Katz* said, I don't think there's any direct way to find out if a `ScaleTransform` is applied to any parent without going through them.

However, if you know that the `ScaleTransform` is applied to the MainGrid, then you can bind `RenderAtScale` to the `ScaleX` or `ScaleY` of the MainGrid's `ScaleTransform`. Maybe this is what you're already doing but I throw it in as a tip anyway

Probably the easiest way to reference the `ScaleTransform` in the Binding is by naming it

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="MainGridScaleTransform" .../>
        </TransformGroup>            
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
```

The Binding should then look similar to this

```
<BitmapCache RenderAtScale="{Binding ElementName=MainGridScaleTransform,
                                     Path=ScaleX}"/>
```

Otherwise, you can get the `ScaleTransform` in the Path with `TransformGroup`

```
<BitmapCache RenderAtScale="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid,
 Path=(LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)}"/>
```

Or without `TransformGroup`

```
<BitmapCache RenderAtScale="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid,
                              Path=(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)}"/>
```

Comment: I get what you're saying. For me, the BitmapCache isn't accessible by my Window. It's stored in the control itself (and said control is actually defined in a separate control library binary), but I understand what you're driving at with the binding and could use that for the "AppliedScale" dependency property I added to the control.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Elad Katz's recommendations, I have created some code to scan up the VisualTree to attempt to total any uniform `ScaleTransform`s. If any one has some optimizations for this algorithms or can think of a few things I may not be considering, let me know. Again, my goal is to get a RenderAtScale that is actually apropriate given the currently applied `ScaleTransform`s. `OnRenderSizeChanged` seems to be an OK place to do this, as it happens AFTER all the layout stuff has run. But, perhaps there is a better place to trigger GetTotalTransformScale()?

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    double totalTransformScale = GetTotalTransformScale();
    BitmapCache bitmapCache = (BitmapCache)MyCachedCanvas.CacheMode;
    if (bitmapCache.RenderAtScale != totalTransformScale)
        bitmapCache.RenderAtScale = totalTransformScale;
}

private double GetTotalTransformScale()
{
    double totalTransform = 1.0d;    
    DependencyObject currentVisualTreeElement = this;            
    do
    {
        Visual visual = currentVisualTreeElement as Visual;
        if (visual != null)
        {
            Transform transform = VisualTreeHelper.GetTransform(visual);

            // This condition is a way of determining if it
            // was a uniform scale transform. Is there some better way?
            if ((transform != null) &&
                (transform.Value.M12 == 0) &&
                (transform.Value.M21 == 0) &&
                (transform.Value.OffsetX == 0) &&
                (transform.Value.OffsetY == 0) &&
                (transform.Value.M11 == transform.Value.M22))
            {                        
                totalTransform *= transform.Value.M11;
            }
        }
        currentVisualTreeElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currentVisualTreeElement);
    }
    while (currentVisualTreeElement != null);

    return totalTransform;
}
```

Comment: I just want to mention that this works only for the special case where we have Scale tranforms only and X and Y scale (M11, M22) are the same. This is most of the thime the case, but does except special cases.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar problem myself: I needed to make one type of control to ignore the `ScaleTransform` on the top level.

`UIElement` has a `RenderTransform` property which is basically the `ScaleTransform` effecting it.